# hibernate : how to put criteria on float types

Tags: hibernate

I am applying criteria on a property of entity which is float and its not working .

```
         Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(MyClass.class);
         float a = (float)0.2;
         crit.add(Restictions.eq("mynumber", a));
```

where mynumber  is my  entity is

```
              @Column(name = "mynumber")
               private float  mynumber;
```

It always gives me empty result , whereas in my table there are rows with mynumber=0.2

If i put any other criteria on any other column  it works , the problem is only with this float type.

any idea what could be the solution

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`floating` numbers follow `IEEE Standard 754` representation and `0.2` may be stored as `0.19999967..`. This makes your comparison fail and hence no result.

To avoid the issue, use `double` or `BigDecimal` if possible.